# Getting an error that I cannot resolve symbol scalafx

Tags: scala

Beginner at scala here, been trying to import scalafx into my scala file but I just can't seem to do so.

```
import scalafx.application.JFXApp

object Main extends JFXApp{

}
```

And the sbt file that I have is

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "SnakeFX"
  )
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "16.0.0-R24"
```

Any fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To use `ScalaFX` you need to add a dependency on the `ScalaFX` library
> and also corresponding version of the `JavaFX`. `JavaFX` binaries are
> system dependent.

You need to tell sbt about the OS you are running, using something like:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  // Determine OS version of JavaFX binaries
  lazy val osName = System.getProperty("os.name") match {
    case n if n.startsWith("Linux") => "linux"
    case n if n.startsWith("Mac") => "mac"
    case n if n.startsWith("Windows") => "win"
    case _ => throw new Exception("Unknown platform!")
  }
  Seq("base", "controls", "fxml", "graphics", "media", "swing", "web")
    .map(m => "org.openjfx" % s"javafx-$m" % "16" classifier osName)
}
```

You can read the entire `ScalaFX` tutorial [here](https://www.scalafx.org/docs/quickstart/).

Assuming you use Intellij, after you modified `build.sbt`, the IDE will see your changes and create a small icon on the top-right to notify you have to load the new changes into the project. The button tells your project to check the `build.sbt` again, and update your dependencies accordingly: either delete removed dependencies or download newly added dependencies.

[image]

After loading them, you should be ready to work with `ScalaFX`. Happy coding!

Comment: I've added this to the sbt but it still throws the error that it cannot resolve the symbol scalafx as well as JFXApp

Comment: Have you loaded the new sbt changes ?

Comment: it just loaded in, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Great, I updated the answer accordingly